# Format date information from string with SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to convert a string like this '160806CD01' into a date like this '2016-08-06 00:00:00' with SQL where the year, month, and date are 16, 8, and 6 respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle is to first extract the part of the string that contains the date, then use a conversion function to turn the string portion it into a date datatype.

The functions to use do vary depending on the RDBMS ; here are some examples :

Oracle :

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(col, 1, 6), 'YYMMDD')
```

MySQL/MariaDB :

```
STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(col, 1, 6), '%y%m%d')
```

SqlServer :

```
CAST(CONCAT('20', SUBSTRING(col, 1, 6)) as datetime)
```

Postgres :

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(col, 1, 6), 'YYMMDD')
```